# how to sort the "p" element entry

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am try to sort the `p` element entry e.g. `(1(a), 1.1, 1, 1(a)-(b))`. How to sort the entry?
**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <sec>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <p><bold>10(a)</bold></p>
        <p><bold>10</bold></p>
        <p><bold>10(b)</bold></p>
        <p><bold>10(d)</bold></p>
        <p><bold>10(c)-(d)</bold></p>
        <p><bold>1</bold></p>
        <sec>
            <title>Title 1(a)</title>
            <p><bold>14(1)</bold></p>
            <p><bold>14</bold></p>
            <p><bold>14(2)</bold></p>
            <p><bold>14(4)</bold></p>
            <p><bold>14(3)-(4)</bold></p>
            <p><bold>10.1</bold></p>
            <p><bold>10</bold></p>
            <p><bold>10.8</bold></p>
        </sec>
    </sec>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <sec>
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <p><bold>1</bold></p>
    <p><bold>10</bold></p>
    <p><bold>10(a)</bold></p>
    <p><bold>10(b)</bold></p>
    <p><bold>10(c)-(d)</bold></p>
    <p><bold>10(d)</bold></p>
    <sec>
      <title>Title 1(a)</title>
      <p><bold>10</bold></p>
      <p><bold>10.1</bold></p>
      <p><bold>10.8</bold></p>
      <p><bold>14</bold></p>
      <p><bold>14(1)</bold></p>
      <p><bold>14(2)</bold></p>
      <p><bold>14(3)-(4)</bold></p>
      <p><bold>14(4)</bold></p>
    </sec>
  </sec>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sec">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <xsl:sort select="bold" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following XSLT 3 captures your intent:

```
  <xsl:template match="sec">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent=". instance of element(p)">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), 'http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Assumes the identity transformation is in place as the base template e.g. in XSLT 3 declared as `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

Comment: I thought the question was about sorting the `p` elements relatively to each other. This will place `<p><bold>2</bold></p>` **after** `<p><bold>10(d)</bold></p>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, right, but this is a question of finding a collation e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), 'http://saxon.sf.net/collation?alphanumeric=yes;ignore-symbols=no', function($p) { $p })"/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), 'http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes', function($p) { $p })"/>`  should sort the `2` before `10(d)`.